# How to get the records from database order by a column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, excel

I have a 50k records are stored in my mysql database. I have to insert 1k records into excel.

So, I am querying the records using limit 0, 1000 and limit 1000, 1000 like this. I have to get records using order by of a particular column. I can do this by queryinng using order by.

But if I have same order by of a particular column records from 990 to 1030 because of this limit 0, 1000 function these are splitting. but I want to get all order by values into same excel. If limit is increased or decreased by 50 or 100 records it is ok for me.

Example:
Actually I am getting first 1000 records as one query using limit 0, 1000. Agian I am getting next 1000 records by using limit 1000, 1000. If I've a records from 990 to 1050 of a same order by column data beacuse of this limit i am getting first 1000 records in one file and when I query next 1k records from 1000 to 2000 records i am getting. but the records 990 to 1050 of a same order by is divided. I want to get all order by records in one excel. Increase of records per query is ok for me but lesthan 100 records

Comment: Is your table data has any primary key?

Comment: So, basically, you want groups of approximately 1000 records where no two groups have the same column values, right? And if that is the case, your question is incomplete: what do you want to happen if you have more than 1000 identical values in that colum? Please update your question.

Comment: Your question is not clear..

Comment: yeah.... I am getting data from 3 tables by joining those tables

Comment: Actually I am getting first 1000 records as one query using limit 0, 1000. Agian I am getting next 1000 records by using limit 1000, 1000. If I've a records from 990 to 1050 of a same order by column data beacuse of this limit i am getting first 1000 records in one file and when I query next 1k records from 1000 to 2000 records i am getting. but the records 990 to 1050 of a same order by is divided. I want to get all order by records in one excel. Increase of records per query is ok for me but lesthan 100 records

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it seems that you only want top 1000 records and a value should not get repeated. In this case, you can use `distinct` clause along with column name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with this SQL

```
selcect distinct(column) from Table group by column  order by column  limt A ,B
```